# keyWindow does not always return a UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow, keywindow

I have been using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` to get the visible view of the screen in the form of a `UIView`. I then convert that view into a `UIImage` to work with. This is working great except in the case where I show a `UIAlertView` at the same time. In that case, `keyWindow` is not returning a `UIWindow` like it normally does, but instead it is returning a `UIModalItemHostingWindow`, and after converting that view into an image it's just a pure black screenshot.

Now the docs say `keyWindow` "holds the UIWindow object in the windows array that is most recently sent the makeKeyAndVisible message."

This `UIModalItemHostingWindow` must be due to the modal alert I'm presenting, perhaps `keyWindow` is returning that view instead of the entire screen.

My question is, how can I always guarantee I get a `UIView` that is an accurate representation of everything visible on screen? It seems `keyWindow` is not a good solution. One workaround is to delay all of the possible alerts I throw, but I would like to find a better solution if possible

Comment: do you have rootviewcontroller in your screen??

Comment: The root view controller is the tab bar controller which is still visible on screen when I try to capture the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]`

instead of `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]`.

That guarantees you get the `UIWindow` which is the ultimate root view of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Traverse all windows in reverse order (just to make less iterations) and check if window's class is strictly `UIWindow`:

```
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    if ([window class] == [UIWindow class]) {
        // do whatever you want with the window object
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! For some reason, there is actually only one window in the windows array when this code is called.

Comment: Even when alert is visible? And is the window of type `UIModalItemHostingWindow`?

Comment: Yes. Technically `UIModalItemHostingWindow` is a `UIWindow` so when I log `[window class]` it prints `UIWindow`, but in the debugger you can see it's a `UIModalItemHostingWindow` when it should be just `UIWindow` like it is when there is no alert on screen.

Comment: I can work around the issue by delaying the alert presentation. I would like to find a better solution if possible.